# How to return and display json data saved to database laravel

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel I am saving input data to json to store it in database, but having trouble displaying the data out again.

I am saving and updating the data as shown in the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'start' => 'required',
        'end' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (Auth::check()) {

        Myroutes::create([ //posting to myroutes table
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'start' => $request->start,
            'end' => $request->end,
            'waypoints' => json_encode($request->waypoints)
        ]);
        return redirect('/my-saved-routes');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}

 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{    
     Myroutes::where('myroute_id', $id)
    ->update(['start' => $request->input('start'),
             'end'=>$request->input('end'),
             'waypoints'=>$request->input('waypoints')]
            );
     return redirect('/my-saved-routes');
}
```

Data is being input into individual input fields in showing.blade:

```
<div id="dynamicInput" class="form-group">
                    <label>Additional Destinations</label>
                    <input type="text" name="waypoints[]" class="form-control" autocomplete="on">
                </div>

                <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');" style="padding:0 10px;">
```

And is being output in edit.blade:

```
<div id="dynamicInput" class="form-group">
                                    <label>Additional Destinations</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="waypoints" class="form-control" autocomplete="on" value="{{ $myroute->waypoints }}">
                                </div>
```

{{ $myroute->waypoints }} shows the entire json array and {{ $myroute->waypoints[0] }}" shows only the first value which is [

Database structure for reference:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhPUC.png)

Output currently showing as:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p560E.png)

Want it to look like the following:
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFI3o.png)

Comment: What kind of format do you expect? An object or an array?

Comment: An array so i can use {{ $myroute->waypoints[0] }} to specify which one to print. Added images into the question to explain futher @devk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you encoded it with `json_encode()`, you should decode it with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true)
```

Setting 2nd argument to true will convert it to an array instead of an object, so you can then do:

```
{{ json_decode($myroute->waypoints, true)[0] }}
```

Also, not relevant to this question, but you're not encoding it in your `update()` method, which will provide very inconsistent results.

Comment: Where do I put the json_decode? In web.php here - `Route::get('/my-saved-routes/edit/{myroute_id}', function ($myroute_id) { 
 
 $myroute = DB::table('myroutes')->where('myroute_id', $myroute_id)->first();

    return view('myroutes.edit', compact('myroute'));
});`

Comment: Wherever you want to get `$myroute->waypoints` in an array. Probably a view, but I don't know

Comment: Aww yes thank you, that worked!! Just need to work out how to display the correct number of input fields to match the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use $casts to archive your goal the "eloquent-way":

```
class Myroutes extends Model {

    /** @var array $casts */
    protected $casts = [
        'waypoints' => 'array'
    ];

}

$mMyroutes = Myroutes::create([
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'start' => $request->start,
    'end' => $request->end,
    'waypoints' => $request->waypoints
]);
```

This way $mMyroutes->waypoints are always handled as an array and stored as json.

Official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting